# How to use collection_check_boxes in a form, via a related model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, form-for

My application contains Events, which own Playlists. A User belongs to one or more Events, and therefore any Playlists owned by the Event:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
  has_many :playlists

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :playlists

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
```

Eg, if EventA contains PlaylistB and PlaylistC, any users who belong to EventA can see both playlists, regardless of who created the playlists.

(It may not be relevant here, but the user management is handled via Devise and the permissions are managed via CanCanCan.)

The associations are working correctly in a rails console, eg I can see all of the Playlists that a User can access:

```
@user = User.first
@user.events.map(&:playlists)
```

My question is, **how do I access this user's Playlists on a `form_for` form?** That is, I would like to include checkboxes for any Playlist belonging to any Event that a User can access.

This line creates checkboxes from all Playlists:

`= f.collection_check_boxes :playlist_ids, Playlist.all, :id, :name`

but I can't see how to limit the checkboxes to just the playlists accessible by this user. I tried:

`= f.collection_check_boxes  :playlist_ids, current_user.events.map(&:playlists), :id, :name`

which returns:

> undefined method `id' for
>   Playlist::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fca5c3f9368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't try this codes yet but I think it will work

```
= f.collection_check_boxes  :playlist_ids, Playlist.where("event_id IN (?)",  current_user.event_ids), :id, :name
```